# Adding custom string to string dependency property in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a DependencyProperty Name as string. Is it possible to use this property together with a custom string in XAML? Something like this:

```
<MyControl.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
        <Binding Source="{Binding Name}" />
        <Binding Source="Custom Text" />
    </MultiBinding>
</MyControl.Text>
```

Comment: why do you use a MultiBinding if you can appent `Custom Text` in `StringFormat`? `Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='{}{0} custom text'}"`

Comment: @ASh: What if I have curly braces in my custom text? Do I just escape them with another curly brace?

Comment: FormatString is getting a bit weird `StringFormat='\{0} custom \{\{}} text'}`. result is `custom {} text`. I prefer `\{` escape sequence over `{}`

Comment: @ASh: Thanks! By the way, if you put that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `MultiBinding` append `Custom Text` to `StringFormat`

```
Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat='{}{0} custom text'}"
```

if text constains `{` and  `}` thay should be escaped as well.

xaml editor interprets them as markup extensions, therefore change `{` to `\{`.

converter interprets `{}` as a place for parameter, therefore double the braces `{{}}`

```
StringFormat='\{0} custom \{\{}} text'
```